# Datatables per session. (Data tables on Client Side)

Tags: asp.net

I have a `datatable` that holds up data for the entire session of a web application. The problem I have is that I can not have more than 1 session, since the `datatable` data gets replaced and then all of the sessions see the same data. I understand that the table is allocated at the server side, is there any way to have instances by session so that each session see its particular data? This has been done in `ASP.NET`. (I am a complete noob regarding web programming so that explains why I did it this way)

Answer (score 1):

The Session collection stores information by Session ID.  The Session ID is generated by ASP.Net and stored as a cookie, and when a new request comes in, ASP.Net reads the cookie to determine which set of session values to provide.  Multiple instances of the same browser (i.e. IE, Chrome) share the same set of cookies, so all of them will connect to the same session instance.  If you want to mimic what two distinct users will see, you could use two different browsers, since Chrome doesn't share its cookies with IE.  If you want to be able to have two different sign-ins on the same kind of browser, you will need to uniquely identify the key you use to store the data table based on the login ID of the individual user.

Comment: So basically, what you are saying is that I should add a column to my data table which identifies the user for the session? This can not be done through some sort of configuration, like some option that would help create different instances of the data objects for each session?

Comment: I meant that the key you use to store the database in the Session should vary.  So the datatable for user "foo" would be stored as Session["foo_data"] and that for user "bar" would be stored as Session["bar_data"].